# Adding music Player to Django App

Tags: javascript, python, django, rest

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    art = models.ImageField(upload_to='art_music/',default='')
    song = models.FileField(upload_to='songs')
```

This is my model file and I am currently making a music player,
Need the music player except  HTML 5.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't used any so far